# Assign value from ADODB.Recordset

Tags: c#, ado.net, adodb

in VBA I assign variables with values retreived from a recordset like this:

```
variable1 = rs("column1")
variable2 = rs("column2")
```

Can I do the same in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADODB has been deprecated for years. For data access in .NET, you should use [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/e80y5yhx.aspx) (DbConnection, DbCommand, DbDataReader, DataSet, DataTable, DbDataAdapter...)

If you really must use ADODB, see [this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/b5c10fbf-d5c0-4e6f-a6ad-151aa9eb004d) on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, do you think you could give me an example of using ADO.NET to do this?

Comment: ADO.NET is a very large subject, I can't really give you a meaningful exemple... However there are plenty of examples in the MSDN documentation.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque - I am having a similar problem. Can you help me ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918848/handling-a-large-adodb-record-set-in-data-table