# Handling a large ADODB record set in data table?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, adodb

I am loading a large result set of about 3 million rows (ADODB record set) into a data table. Its taking too long to even load the result set into a data table. I want to find out a way of extracting only part of a result set and then loading it into a DataTable. Alternatively, is there a way to directly read the recordset directly instead of loading it into a data table and then reading it ?

This is the code I use to fill my DataTable -

```
OleDbDataAdapter oleDA = new OleDbDataAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
oleDA.Fill(dt, myADODBRecordset);
```

Comment: Depends...Do you have access to the database query or stored procedure?  Are u wanting to handle batches of data at a time?

Comment: @StinkyTowel - I have access to the database query. But, i'd prefer not to edit it. Anyway, I am still eager to learn all possible solutions to my problem.

Comment: Could you consider using an System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader(v=vs.110).aspx this will allow forward only access to the data, but will mean you won't have to load the whole dataset into memory.

Comment: @SamPlusPlus - I have some questions. Can you answer them for me ? - Will it be able to read data from an ADODB recordset ? Will there be any way to control the number of rows I can read at a time ? Is there any kind of disk caching involved ? Thanks.

Comment: @blasto How are getting your dataset? Could you use a data reader instead of getting a ADODB Recordset?

Comment: @blasto - what are you using the data for?  3M rows can is a crap-ton and extremely heavy depending on what's in the data.  Do you need all of it once?

Comment: @StinkyTowel - I don't need it all at once really. I did not want to change my code, thats why i was trying to do it that way. Now, I am fetching data in batches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some options to consider:

1. Get only the rows and columns you really need to work with.
2. Get some data and let the user ask for the next set of rows when they want to.
3. Write optimized SQL queries
4. Don't use a DataTable unless you have to because it contains more metadata information that other list-type objects.
5. Consider using a managed .NET provider.

Comment: I am already doing 1 and 2. I don't know is meant by 3. 4 - I need to iterate the recordset as if it was a database table in memory. Is there another class to do this ? 5. What is that ?

Answer (score -1):

Why load so large data into memory? A large data transaction must comsume large resource, so optimize your code, or use EF.

Comment: What is EF ? Never heard of it.